# How to identify which pattern in where clause matched

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need help on T-SQL. I have a stored procedure in my SQL Server with query (sample) as below:

```
Select empid, empname, sal from emp
  where empname like '%jo%'
  and   empname like '%el%'
```

Let's say, the above query returns records as shown below:

```
empid empname sal   
17    john    $1000
45    elena   $2000
```

I need to have another column to the above select statement which should say `'jo'` for `%jo%` record and `'el'` for `%el%` record. For example:

```
empid empname sal     SearchString
17    john    $1000   jo
45    elena   $2000   el
```

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Your current where clause won't return either of those two rows - `'john'` is not like both `'%jo%'` and `'%el%'`. I think you meant to have `OR` instead of `AND`. Also can you please specify which version of SQL Server you're using?

Comment: Also what do you want if the search strings are `'jo'` and `'oh'`, which will match `'john'` twice? Do you want two rows, do you want `'jo,el'` to be returned, or do you want to pick an arbitrary one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cater for multiple conditions you can make use of a `CTE`

- to create an in-memory table
- join the actual table to this in-memory table
- retrieve the condition in the select clause

**SQL Statement**

```
;WITH Conditions (SearchString) AS (
  SELECT 'jo' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'el'
)
SELECT  empid
        , empname
        , sal
        , Searchstring
FROM    emp e
        INNER JOIN Conditions c ON e.empname LIKE '%' + c.SearchString + '%'
```

**Test script**

```
;WITH Conditions (SearchString) AS (
  SELECT 'jo' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'el'
)
, emp (empid, empname, sal) AS (
    SELECT 17, 'john', 1000 UNION ALL
    SELECT 45, 'elena', 2000
)
SELECT  empid
        , empname
        , sal
        , Searchstring
FROM    emp e
        INNER JOIN Conditions c ON e.empname LIKE '%' + c.SearchString + '%'
```

Comment: Thanks. Your test script works fine. I am wondering how to implement this in my SP. I am getting the searchstrings as comma separated parameter.

Comment: You should mention all relevant information when asking a question. That was relevent information <g>. You have a few options. 1. parse the input parameter (not good). 2. Pass a table variable type to the stored procedure (best) 3. Pass an XML parameter (good). This all depends on wether you can change the way your sp is called but that is something you would have to tell us.

Comment: @Javeed Can you explain? How does this work with passing `'jo,el'` into your procedure? To me it seemed that the main challenge you had was turning that comma-separated string into distinct values. I'm no trying to take anything away from this answer but I'm not sure how it solves that problem.

Comment: I have parsed the input parameter already. This solves my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to this will work, noting you can pass in the parameter to the stored proc

```
declare @empname varchar(255)
set @empname = 'jo'

Select empid, empname, sal, @empname as searchstring from emp 
  where empname like '%'+@empname+'%'
```

Comment: Yes. the values are passed to SP as a comma separated value and I am splitting the parameter and constructing the query. However, as mentioned in my OP, I have multiple conditions "where empname like '%jo%' and empname like '%el%'".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to know which search string matched for any given output row.  Discounting the possibility of matching more than one search string, e.g. `empname` 'Joel', the following should work:

```
declare @emp as table (empid int, empname varchar(10), sal money)
insert into @emp ( empid, empname, sal ) values
  ( 17, 'john', 1000 ),
  ( 45, 'elena', 2000 )

select empid, empname, sal,
  case
    when empname like '%jo%' then 'jo'
    when empname like '%el%' then 'el'
    else '?'
    end as SearchString
  from @emp
  where empname like '%jo%' or empname like '%el%'
```

Comment: The challenge is creating the `where` clause, since the value(s) come into the stored procedure as a string (e.g. `jo,el`) not as individual parameters.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Oh, that requirement that isn't in the OP, but buried as a comment on another answer.  My bad.  Though the comment does state that the CSV string is already being parsed and used to construct the query on the fly.

Comment: It was a comment on the first answer posted over three hours ago. While I agree it's on the OP to include that information on the question, it's also on us to read the other answers and comments before throwing an answer over the wall.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you need to parse comma-separated strings, you should have a split function. Here is the one I use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrings]
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN ( SELECT Item FROM (
     SELECT Item = x.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
        FROM ( SELECT [XML] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
                + REPLACE(@List, ',', '</i><i>') 
                + '</i>').query('.') ) AS a 
        CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i)
    ) AS y WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
   );
GO
```

Now assuming you want to pick an arbitrary match in the case of multiple matches, you can say:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Search
    @SearchStrings NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ;WITH x AS (
        SELECT e.empid, e.empname, e.sal, SearchString = s.Item,
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.empid ORDER BY s.Item)
        FROM dbo.emp AS e
        INNER JOIN dbo.SplitStrings(@SearchStrings) AS s
        ON e.empname LIKE '%' + s.Item + '%'
    ) 
    SELECT empid, empname, sal, SearchString
    FROM x WHERE rn = 1 ORDER BY empid;
END
GO
```

(That will return the first *alphabetical* match in your `@SearchStrings` parameter, not the first match in order of your comma-separated string.)

If you just want all the rows, even if an employee comes up for more than one of the passed in patterns (which means `'john'` would be returned twice if your parameter was `'jo,oh'`), you can just say:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Search
    @SearchStrings NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT e.empid, e.empname, e.sal, SearchString = s.Item
      FROM dbo.emp AS e
      INNER JOIN dbo.SplitStrings(@SearchStrings) AS s
      ON e.empname LIKE '%' + s.Item + '%'
      ORDER BY empid;
END
GO
```

If you need a comma-separated list of the matches in cases where more than one pattern matched an employee, please state that in your requirements. It's a little more work to do that.